Typescript import statement causes: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" at Runtime in ASP.NET Project
I have followed Microsofts official guide to implement SignalR into my existing ASP.NET project (.NET 6). I am now running into a problem because of some problem with my existing Typescript configuration. Each Typescript file is built into it's own Javascript file, instead of being bundled via Webpack, that can then be referenced onto the cshtml. I will not explain this decision, but using a bundler is not an option for this project.
All seems to be fine when developing the Typescript file, but at runtime i get the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" at run time".
My project configuration:
The TS import statement in question:
import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr"

export namespace SignalRNameSpace{
    export class SignalR{

tsconfig.json:
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "module": "Preserve",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "wwwroot/js/appscripts/",
    "rootDir": "wwwroot/ts",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "include": [
    "./wwwroot/ts/**/*"
  ]
}

What ive tried:
**1. **Changing module to commonjs in tsconfig:
"module": "Preserve",
**2. **Adding type="module" to script tag: Resulting in:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@microsoft/signalr". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

**3.  **Referencing using "require"
import { signalR } from "@microsoft/signalr"

Error TS2305  (TS) Module '"@microsoft/signalr"' has no exported member 'signalR'.

PS. I have installed both @microsoft/signalr, as well as @types/signalr
Also, i have tried using webpack to just individually bundle this file and this worked very well until it came to merging with my master branch, as azure pipelines through the followinf error:
"##[error]ICompare6\wwwroot\ts\SignalR\ManualReconSignalR.ts(1,26): Error TS2307: Build:Cannot find module '@microsoft/signalr' or its corresponding type declarations.
"
Also i would prefer if i didnt have two different typescript configurations in my project.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

import * as signalR from "@microsoft/signalr"  Without a bundler referencing an NPM module in this way won't work.

oh, why is that? what should i do instead?

Because @microsoft/signalr doesn't mean anything from the browser, browsers have no built in support for accessing NPM modules.  import from the browsers are in the form import * as signalR from "https://some.url.com".    Your webpack route should work, but I'm no expert on azure pipelines, and it looks like it's trying to compile for you anyway, is "@microsoft/signalr" in your package.json as a dependency?

yes it is in my package.json

Also, even if the browser would be able to access files from node_modules, you probably would not want to copy and serve the whole node_modules folder. So you need to pick only the code that is actually needed anyway. A bundler would take care of that. - But there are options to include the SignalR client via script tag, instead of import
